# java aes Encrypt matches in c#

Tags: java, c#

this is the java code:

```
import javax.crypto.*;
import javax.crypto.spec.SecretKeySpec;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.security.InvalidKeyException;
import java.security.MessageDigest;
import java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException;
import java.security.SecureRandom;

public class Main {


    /**
     * entry the content
     *
     * @param content  the content need to entry
     * @param password the key
     * @return
     */
    public static String md5Aessign(String content, String password) {

        MessageDigest md;
        try {

            KeyGenerator kgen = KeyGenerator.getInstance("AES");

            SecureRandom random = SecureRandom.getInstance("SHA1PRNG");
            random.setSeed(password.getBytes());
            kgen.init(128, random);

            SecretKey secretKey = kgen.generateKey();
            byte[] enCodeFormat = secretKey.getEncoded();
            SecretKeySpec key = new SecretKeySpec(enCodeFormat, "AES");
            Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES");
            cipher.init(Cipher.ENCRYPT_MODE, key);


            byte[] byteContent = content.getBytes("GBK");

            md = MessageDigest.getInstance("MD5");
            md.update(byteContent);
            byte[] result = cipher.doFinal(md.digest());

            return parseByte2HexStr(result);

        } catch (NoSuchAlgorithmException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (NoSuchPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (InvalidKeyException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IllegalBlockSizeException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (BadPaddingException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }

    /**
     *
     *
     * @param buf
     * @return
     */

    public static String parseByte2HexStr(byte buf[]) {
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        for (int i = 0; i < buf.length; i++) {
            String hex = Integer.toHexString(buf[i] & 0xFF);
            if (hex.length() == 1) {
                hex = '0' + hex;
            }
            sb.append(hex.toUpperCase());
        }
        return sb.toString();
    }


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Hello World!");

        String content = "Hello World!";
        String key = "1234567812345678";

        System.out.println(md5Aessign(content, key));
    }
}
```

**Well ,I want implement it in c#. Here is the code...**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace TestDes
{
    class Test
    {
        public static string Encrypt(string toEncrypt, string key)
        {
            MD5CryptoServiceProvider md5 = new MD5CryptoServiceProvider();
            byte[] temp = Encoding.GetEncoding("GBK").GetBytes(toEncrypt);
            byte[] toEncryptArray = md5.ComputeHash(temp);

            RijndaelManaged rDel = new RijndaelManaged();
            var aes = new AesManaged();
            var sha1 = new SHA1Managed();

            var byteHash = sha1.ComputeHash(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(key));
            var truncatedHash = new byte[16];
            Array.Copy(byteHash, truncatedHash, Math.Min(truncatedHash.Length, byteHash.Length));

            rDel.KeySize = 128;
            rDel.BlockSize = 128;
            rDel.Key = truncatedHash;
            rDel.Mode = CipherMode.ECB; 
            rDel.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7; 
            ICryptoTransform crypto = rDel.CreateEncryptor();

            byte[] cryptData = crypto.TransformFinalBlock(toEncryptArray, 0, toEncryptArray.Length);

            return ParseByte2HexStr(cryptData);

        }

        /// <summary>
        /// 
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="buffer"></param>
        /// <returns></returns>
        public static string ParseByte2HexStr(byte[] buffer)
        {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            for (int i = 0; i < buffer.Length; i++)
            {
                sb.Append(buffer[i].ToString("X2"));
            }
            return sb.ToString();
        }

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            String content = "Hello World!";
            String key = "1234567812345678";

            Console.WriteLine(Encrypt(content, key));

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

but it don't matches...

java output : C9BA133078BB8AE69FB56D2F76D5E5D17ECC29AFA9533026D2CF87C4DFAE29D9
c# output :   A7280364DD9AC4A1867AAF22C049EC05C7225A807FB0E39E0BFF3047382EF901

I want the c# equals the java. *platform: jdk 1.7; .net 4.0.*

Comment: are you using the right variant of sha1?

Comment: What is going on here, can you descrive your code, are you sure that both codes should generate the same output?

Comment: @Rocketq  I know there has some problem in my c# code. What I need is to make the c# output equals the java ouput.

Comment: @user1666620  what is the problem?

Comment: the problem is that in java, you are using the "SHA1PRNG" algorithm to derive the key from the password, while in C# you are just using a simple SHA1. Two different algorithm generates different keys for the encrytion so the result will be different. You need to find a .NET implementation of the "SHA1PRNG".

Comment: so this is the random generator you need to find or implement in .NET: http://www.docjar.com/html/api/sun/security/provider/SecureRandom.java.html

Comment: If the clear text is > 1 block you should not be using ECB mode